# how do i initialize 2 static members belonging to 2 different derived classes

Tags: c++, oop, object, inheritance, static

New to c++. I'm solving questions to understand better.

So, i have to make a program which has a parent class called `Person` and it has 2 derived classes named `Student` and `Professor`. The parent class `Person` has normal variables - `std::string name` and `int age`. The derived class `Student` has variables `int sum`, `int marks[6]` and `static int cur_id`. The derived class `Professor` has variables `int publications` and `static int cur_id`.

Now both the derived classes have 2 overloaded methods, `getdata()` - gets input from user and `putdata()`  - prints data.

Also both have a `static` variable named `cur_id` which gets incremented when an object gets constructed.

Now the problem comes when i try to initialize the static variables using the below code -

```
int Student::cur_id;
int Professor::cur_id;
```

I get the following error -
`'int Professor::cur_id': redeclaration of member is not allowed`.

here is the full code -

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Person
{
protected:
    std::string name;
    int age;
public:
    Person()
        :age(0)
    {}
};

class Professor : public Person
{
private:
    int publications;
    static int cur_id;

public:
     Professor()                     //constructor
        :Person(), publications()
    {
        ++cur_id;
    }
    void getdata()
    {
        std::cin >> name >> age >> publications;
    }
    void putdata()
    {
        std::cout << name << " " << age << " " << publications << " " << cur_id << std::endl;
    }
    


};




class Student : public Person
{
private:
    int marks[6];
    static  int cur_id;
    int sum;
public:

    Student()                               //constructor
        :marks{ 0 }, sum(0), Person()
    {
        ++cur_id;
    }
    
    void getdata() 
    {
        std::cin >> name >> age;
        for (int index{}; index < 6; ++index)
        {
            std::cin >> marks[index];
            sum += marks[index];
        }
    }
    void putdata()
    {
        std::cout << name << " " << age << " " << sum << " " << cur_id;
    }
    

};
int Student::cur_id;
int Professor::cur_id;


int main()
{

    Student student;
    student.getdata();
    student.putdata();
    Student nobita;
    nobita.getdata();
    nobita.putdata();


    return 0;

}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: `Professor::cur_id` is  not static.

Comment: @Quimby thanks for pointing out my mistake. I do these type of mistakes a lot, can you give pointers on how i can minimize these types of mistakes??Thanks

Comment: Well, not meaning to offend, but read the error message. It  says "redeclaration of member" which means not a  static in this context. In C++ the error messages are often cryptic or very long but they always say what the compiler sees. So, do not look them as "the compiler is not doing what I want" but as "i did not write what I wanted correctly and I should explain it better to the compiler". But do not sweat it too much, it happens and will get easier through experience.

Comment: Also, I recommend turning on more compiler warnings  `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` and `-Werror` which treats all warnings as compiler errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should define cur_id in Professor class as static.